# Unity 3d PhotonEngine How other player can get data generated by masterclient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, multiplayer, photon

hello I need help with an online 2 players game with photon. Each player receives a generated ticket number, player 1, will guest player2' s ticket number and player2 will guest also player1' s ticket number.

Here is a script for the master client to generate the tickets. When player 2 joins the room he will get his tickets from the ticket generated by player 1 (the master client). I created a game object with photo view attached to it and the script here

```
void Start()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        player1ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000);
        player2ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000);
    }
    getTicket = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (getTicket)
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            myTicket = player1ticket;
        }
        else
        {
            myTicket = player2ticket;
        }
        getTicket = false;
    }
}
```

But When playing the game the player 2 doesn't have any ticketnumber

Answer (score 1):

First all you know that it might happen that both get the same ticket number - not very probable but possible. You might want to repeat the second random in such a case

```
player1ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000);
do
{
    player2ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000); 
} 
while(player2ticket == player1ticket);
```

Then well you only generate the values at the master. So on the client `getTicket` is never `true`.

And even if it would the client doesn't have the `player2ticket` value neither.

There is also no need/sense of assigning them every frame in Update.

---

I would rather use the **Custom Room Properties** and on the master use [`Room.SetCustomProperties`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_room.html#a3fb1bbb640e96bdaa4f24a65e276edbb) which will trigger [`OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(Hashtable`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_mono_behaviour_pun_callbacks.html#acd0123ad271eaa8bc372debcd33d0e31) on all clients. This call is also triggered once after a client joins a room so you can be sure a newly connected clients won't miss it.

```
void Start()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        player1ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000);
        player2ticket = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 5000);

        // You are master so already get your ticket
        myTicket = player1ticket;

        // Then simply push the other ticket(s) into the room properties
        Hashtable properties = PhotonNetwork.room.customProperties; 
        properties["ticket2"] =  player2ticket);  

        // This will store the value in the current room
        // and triggers OnRoomPropertiesUpdate on all already connected clients
        PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties(properties);
    }
}

// This will be called
// - as soon as you entered a room
// - whenever someone writes into the room properties
public override void OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(Hashtable propertiesThatChanged)
{
    // Not sure about the exact API right now, it's not in their docs
    // it's either ContainsKey, HasKey or something similar ..maybe even TryGetValue works
    if(!propertiesThatChanged.ContainsKey("ticket2")) return;

    if(!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        myTicket = (int) PhotonNetwork.room.customProperties["ticket2"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I got errors on room  Hashtable properties = PhotonNetwork.room.customProperties; and on OnRoomPropertiesUpdate

Comment: @user3840726 what errors? It's probably because you don't have the according `using ExitGames.Client.Photon;` (afaik this should be the namespace) for the `Hashtable`

Comment: I have it but I can't have CustomProperties with PhotonNetwork.room but I don't have any  errors when I change room by CurrentRoom